# Kafka ACLs for AWS Lambda SelfManagedKafka event source mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, confluent-cloud

I'm attempting to use an AWS Lambda [SelfManagedKafka event source mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-selfmanagedkafka.html), as described in [Using Lambda with self-managed Apache Kafka](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kafka.html). Confluent Cloud is being used to host the Kafka cluster the event source will use.

On creation of the event source mapping (via SAM/CloudFormation template), though, the trigger is showing the following as the "Last processing result":

`PROBLEM: Cluster failed to authorize Lambda.`

Based on the [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kafka.html#kafka-authorize-errors), this error indicates...

> that the provided user doesn't have all of the following required Kafka access control list (ACL) permissions: [list truncated]

I've verified that the listed permissions are in place for the group, cluster, and topic which leaves me to suspect that the issue has something to do with the following note:

> The group name must match the event source mapping's UUID.

My tentative take on that note is that it's suggesting the group name has to match the physical ID of the event source mapping which is generated on creation. I've been unable to track down any further documentation that would elucidate that note. I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this before and can confirm?

If that is true, it would seem that the expected workflow is to create the event source mapping, get the physical ID from the output, and then create the Kafka ACLs.

Answer (score 1):

After digging around further, I found at least a partial answer to this question by manually creating the event source mapping via the AWS Console. The UI enables one to optionally specify the name of the consumer group identifier, and includes the following help text for the input field:

> The ID of a Kafka consumer group to join. If the consumer group ID you specify doesn't exist, or if you leave this field blank, Lambda generates a unique value.

If none is provided, the UUID of the event source mapping seems to be the value used.

As an alternative to taking that generated value and creating a consumer group in Kafka with that name, one can also add the CREATE permission on the cluster itself to the consumer's ACL. This enables Lambda to create the group on Kafka as well.